# How to remove this protruding mass inside a self-intersecting object?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, knife-tool, intersection

Inside view of the object with the protruding edge that I want to remove.
[image: Inner part of the object]

Outside view of the object. The tubular portion intersects the body and results in the protruding mass that I want to remove.
[image: Outer part of the object]

I have tried selecting around the intersection and using the `Intersecting (knife)` tool, but it always leaves behind unwanted artifacts.

selection:
[image]

knife intersect tool result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you don't have any duplicate overlapping vertices and faces by going into *Edit Mode* with <kbd>tab</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance*. Then select only either the cylinder or the other object. In my case I selected the cylinder part and did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> *> Intersect (Knife)*. And it cut the mesh correctly.

[image]

However, I would not recommend boolean operation for your mesh as you can end up with ugly geometry that can become problematic. You can easily get a nice perfect quad topology, but first enable [`LoopTools`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlSY8.gif) via menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Add-ons* → *LoopTools*:

[image]

Then select a nice edge outline with equal amount of edges as the end of your cylindrical opening. For example in my case I have a cylinder with 32 edges, so therefore I select a region on the other object surrounded by 32 edges. It does not necessarily need to be a square. You may need to experiment highlighting several sets of edges to find the perfect combination of the exact amount of edges as your cylindrical opening. Then go to menu *Select > Select Loops > Select Loop Inner-Region*.

[image]

Click <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> LoopTools > Circle* and then press <kbd>i</kbd> to inset faces and then <kbd>X</kbd> *> Delete Faces*. Now you have a beautiful hole to connect to.

[image]

Now select the edge loop of the cylindrical opening and the edge loop of the object you want to connect to and go to menu *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops* and increase *Number of Cuts* as needed.

[image]